# Отображение большого rtf-текстового файла в scroll-элементе Swing

Tags: java, swing, текст

Подскажите, пожалуйста, API для отображения текстового файла rtf весом в 1 гигабайт в окне swing приложения. Возможно, в связи с большим объемом файла, необходимо отображать часть документа, а остальную выгружать из некого кеша во время скроллирования?

Comment: Как работать с rtf: https://github.com/joniles/rtfparserkit
Другой вопрос как считывать частями, наверное надо будет расширить/обернуть https://github.com/joniles/rtfparserkit/blob/master/src/main/java/com/rtfparserkit/parser/IRtfSource.java и изменить парсер, выглядит не просто

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Единственный вариант реализации нашел на гитхабе - проект LLPAD (https://github.com/riversun/LLPAD). Подредактировав его, за небольшое время, проект был приспособлен под мои цели - логгер в небольшой панели с добавляющимися записями